# Como exibir o "Pressione qualquer tecla para continuar" em C++?

Tags: c++

Em C, eu coloco o "Pressione qualquer tecla para continuar" com o comando getchar(). em C++, como eu o faço?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode usar a função [`getchar()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/getchar) mesmo.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Pressione qualquer tecla para continuar..." << endl;
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Não funciona, pois se algum gringo for usar o código, não vai souber o que está escrito.

Comment: @CypherPotato Até aonde entendi o autor pediu apenas como mostrar o texto "Pressione qualquer tecla para continuar...". Ao meu ver o exemplo responde exatamente o que foi perguntando. Concorda? +1 para resposta.

Comment: Sim, de um certo ponto está certo. Porém se ele for ter que distribuir, irá ter que usar o método do cara abaixo.

Comment: @CypherPotato Eu não entendi, distribuir exatamente o que e para que? Se tem alguma sugestão de uso melhor por favor poste uma resposta, garanto que um voto já terá (dependendo da resposta), o meu (:

Comment: @CypherPotato Funcionar, funciona =) O AP não explicitou este fato que tu disse, mas se for preciso exibir o texto noutra língua, pode-se usar o [`cin.get()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/get/). Ou se for preciso algo mais *elaborado*, usar a função [`GetSystemDefaultUILanguage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318123%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) para detectar a linguagem do S.O e exibir o texto naquela linguagem. Sobre o `system("pause")`, é algo apenas Windows, dê uma olhada também [nesta questão do SO](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1107705/1608936).

Comment: Aham, mas ele não iria ter que usar uma `Switch` para cada lingua do sistema, iria pegar algo mais dinâmico, correto?

Comment: @CypherPotato Se for usar a função `GetSystemDefaultUILanguage` ou `GetUserDefaultUILanguage`, ela vai retornar um [*identificador do idioma*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318693(v=vs.85).aspx), esse *identificador* você compara com um idioma especifico, por exemplo o francês, e imprime o texto nesta linguagem. =)

Comment: @CypherPotato Realmente eu só queria usar isso. Não vou ter que distribuir no momento.

Comment: Não uso C++, desculpa...

Comment: Não há o que desculpar, @CypherPotato =)

Comment: Obrigado haha :D

Answer (score 0):

Para exibir o "Pressione qualquer tecla para continuar", você deve incluir a biblioteca `<cstdlib>` e adicionar `system("pause")` no local desejado.

Note, porém, que essa função não retorna a tecla pressionada, somente pausa a execução e a resume após o pressionamento.

Comment: Eu estou num ambiente Linux. O system("pause") não vai funcionar aqui. Mas consegui. Incluí a biblioteca <stdio.h>, a mesma do C, no C++, mantive minha <iostream> e coloquei o getchar();

Comment: Eu queria tira essa mensagem de "Pressione qualquer tecla para continuar" e mesmo assim o programa ter a pausa, tem como?